# how to use masonry in swift 3.0

Tags: swift3, masonry

```
Objective-C

[textView mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
    make.edges.mas_equalTo(UIEdgeInsetsZero).priorityLow();
    make.top.mas_equalTo(imageView.mas_bottom).offset(20);
}];
```

I want change swift code. please help me??   thanks.

Comment: What do you want to do and what is your problem? What have you tried to solve it yourself?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These code make work

```
btn.mas_makeConstraints { (make:MASConstraintMaker?) in
    make?.top.equalTo()(view.mas_top)?.with().offset()(0)
    make?.left.equalTo()(view.mas_left)?.with().offset()(0)
    make?.right.equalTo()(view.mas_right)?.with().offset()(0)
    make?.bottom.equalTo()(view.mas_bottom)?.with().offset()(0)
    return()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The shortest way to do it (if you want to mirror `edges` of parent view is)

```
    self.xibView .mas_makeConstraints( { make in
        _ = make?.edges.equalTo()(self)
    })
```

This assignment `_ =` also will silence the warning about un-assignment.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [SnapKit](http://snapkit.io), which is the Swift only version of Masonry. It looks like they have decided not to deprecate Masonry, as was previously the case, but is still a good idea for your Swift only projects. If you are familiar with [Masonry](https://github.com/SnapKit/Masonry), you can migrate to SnapKit very easily.

Comment: The only caveat to my own advice is that SnapKit support doesn't go back very far. I've run into support issues for macOS, they only support 10.11+.

Comment: Some people have to not use swift frameworks unfortunatly